# How to find when a specific character is typed in textarea

Tags: angularjs

We have requirement to show a drop down when user enters a "@".

I am planning to have a directive as following:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {  
    $scope.values = ['@'];
    $scope.valuesEntered = false;
});

app.directive('identifier', function ($parse) {
    return {
        scope: {
          values: '=values'
        },
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
          elm.bind('keypress', function(e){
            var char = String.fromCharCode(e.which||e.charCode||e.keyCode), matches = [];
            angular.forEach(scope.values, function(value, key){
              if(char === value) matches.push(char);
            }, matches);
            if(matches.length !== 0){
              $scope.valuesEntered = true;
            }
          });
        }
    }   
});
```

Will this be ok ?

Comment: For reference, You can take a look here : https://github.com/fraserxu/ng-textcomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple directive I made that will allow you to specify an expression to evaluate when a given key is pressed or one of an array of keys is pressed.

Note that this is a one-way street. There is currently no going back once you have detected that keypress, even if the user pressed backspace.

```js
var app = angular.module('sample', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.values = ['@', '!'];
  $scope.valuesEntered = false;
  $scope.valuesEntered2 = false;
});

app.directive('whenKeyPressed', function($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      action: '&do'
    },
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
      var charCodesToMatch = [];
      attrs.$observe('whenKeyPressed', function(keys) {
        if (angular.isArray(keys))
          charCodesToMatch = keys.map(function(key) {
            if (angular.isString(key))
              return key.charCodeAt(0);
          });
        else if (angular.isString(keys))
          charCodesToMatch = keys.split('').map(function(ch) {
            return ch.charCodeAt(0);
          });
      });

      elm.bind('keypress', function(e) {
        var charCode = e.which || e.charCode || e.keyCode;
        if (charCodesToMatch.indexOf(charCode) > -1)
          scope.action();
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="sample">
  <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <p>Values "@" entered? {{valuesEntered}}</p>
    <textarea ng-model="str" when-key-pressed="@" do="valuesEntered = true"></textarea>

    <p>Values {{values}} entered 2: {{valuesEntered2}}</p>
    <textarea ng-model="str2" when-key-pressed="{{values}}" do="valuesEntered2 = true"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Plunkr demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/xXNaA14H6UHKRGrrhRh3?p=preview)